# EntityFramework - Weird behaviour

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I've got two Tables called **BeverageCapacity** and **ClubsBeverage**. Also there are Controller for both called **BeverageCapacityController** and  **ClubsBeverageController**. Here's a picture of the Data inside **BeverageCapacity**-Table:

[image: Picture to show columns]

Now I want to delete all rows where the ClubsBeverageID is "18":

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
public void RemoveByClubsBeverageID(int clubsBeverageID)
{
    // Get all BeverageCapacities
    var all = GetAll();

    // Filter the BeverageCapacites which should be deleted
    var removableEntities = all.Where(bCap => bCap.ClubsBeverageID == clubsBeverageID).ToList();

    foreach (var beverageCapacity in removableEntities)
    {
        Context.BeverageCapacity.Remove(beverageCapacity);
    }

    Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

*I know this could be written more efficient and readable, but for simplicity this is good enough.*

So if I call this Method directly (I do it via Swagger), all rows are deleted as expected but now comes the clue: If I call the Method **RemoveByClubsBeverageID** via an other Controller(in this example **ClubsBeverge**), I get this result:

[image]

It seems like the Row with **ClubsBeverageID** 18 was deleted, but the one with ID 17 changed it's **ClubsBeverageID** to 18.

Here is also the code for **ClubsBeverageController**:

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
public void Update(DTOUpdateClubsBeverage cBev)
{
    // Get the existing ClubsBeverage
    var cb = Get(cBev.ClubsBeverageID);

    // Remove all Capacities
    var cc = new BeverageCapacityController(Context);
    cc.RemoveByClubsBeverageID(cBev.ClubsBeverageID);

    // here are the rows already changes because of SaveChanges in BeverageCapacityController

    ...
}
```

I cannot imagine what is happening here but this seems like a Bug to me.
Also the .net Framework, .net Core, and so on are all up to date.

Maybe someone knows why this is happening

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are 100% sure no other code is executing? e.g. other users of the web app

Comment: I am sure for 105%. Also I would see VS hitting the Breakpoint of there is something else executing this code

Comment: What SQL commands are executed by `Context.SaveChanges();` inside `RemoveByClubsBeverageID` method?

Comment: Because I am using the Core Version I don't know how to view that sql command. Do you know how to do so?

Comment: I noticed, that you pass `Context` from one controller to another. Try to create new individual instance of `DbContext` for each method.

Comment: You should of course no call a Controller form another controller. RemoveByClubsBeverageID() should be in another class (as an injectable  Service). Not the core problem here but possibly related.

Comment: There is a lot we don't see here - that Get() method, your POCO classes and espc their maaping to the Db..

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov I have read that each time a HttpMethod is called, one Context should be created and used until the complete function was finished (across methods). So this is wrong?

Comment: @bommelding I didn't think the Get() or POCO classes are needed so I left them. There is nothing special inside them, just Mapping the Properties to teh equivalent Column. And the Get() returns ALL entries from the Database

Comment: @DanielDirtyNativeMartin, wrong or not depends on various factors, but to isolate problem, you should create new `Context`, instead of transfering existed one to another controller.

Comment: Well I did it now with Database relations, so there is no need for me to delete manually. This way it works as expected, but I try to implement it the other way to find out whats causing this issue